# Background image Cut when I do Zoom In

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a project using `bootstrap 3.3.7`. I have a background image on the front page.

**Image displaying perfectly in my computer like:** [image].

**But when I Zoom In this image cuts from top and bottom like:**

[image: Image 2]

**Html Code is:**

```
<div class="bg-img">
    <div class="container" style="color:#fff;padding: 56px 0 85px 0px">
        <h1 class="container" style="font-size:51px;font-weight:600;margin-bottom:30px;">Work Different</h1>
        <div class="row container" style="margin-bottom:12px;">
            <p class="col-md-3" style="width:29%">Provide your organization a powerful work execution platform that offers exceptional speed to business value — so you say yes to more ideas, more customers, and more revenue.</p>
            <p class="col-md-9"></p>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="container"><a class="btn nav-btn-green" href="/SignUp">Try Risk Hippie for Free</a></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**My background image CSS style is:**

```
   .bg-img {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url(/img/newbackground.png);
    margin-top:-9px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 25px 0px 25px -25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), inset 567px 0 170px -25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 25px 0px 25px -25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), inset 567px 0 170px -25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    box-shadow: inset 25px 0px 25px -25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), inset 567px 0 170px -25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
}
```

Image is not responsive when I zoom in to my browser.

Comment: it's normal, because background-size is cover

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: @Alex I tried all the option of `background-size`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you specify the size of a background image with "auto"

```
.bg_img{
        background-size: auto;
    }
```

Comment: using `auto` it cuts more than an image as before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possible try:

```css
.bg_img{
    background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```